# Using ctypes for QGIS Python plugin to bind DLL

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, dll

I'm trying to build a Python plugin in QGIS which does some raster image processing. The processing itself is done via a .dll. Hence, I'd like to bind it with ctypes. First of all: is it possible to use ctypes with a Python plugin in QGIS? Secondly, if yes, what am I doing wrong if I am getting the following error?

[image]

> OSError: [WinError 126] The specified modul could not be found

The plugin was created using the plugin builder and following [this](http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html) tutorial. It's a dock widget and is besides the processing function vanilla.

What I tried so far:

- Checked if the .dll exists in the specified location
- Ran a mwe only loading the dll and doing the processing in both a conda environment and using the Python executable in c:\Program Files\QGIS 3.14\apps\Python37\ -> Both worked without problems
- Used `os.chdir` and changed to directory where the .dll is located -> No effect
- Tried different things with the directory string (raw, forward slash, double backward slash)
- Added the directory containing the dll to the Windows `PATH`

I've read that it could be related to a missing dependency. However, I'm not sure how to pin-point the problem as it seems to run in both tested Python environments.

Comment: I've sometimes had issues with certain programs not working from inside of QGIS due its environmental variables interfering somehow (as far as I can tell). See e.g.: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380049/activating-a-conda-environment-from-within-qgis-cannot-be-done-due-to-inherit
If you export from within QGIS the state of the environmental variables, then set them externally, then start the QGIS Python3.7 exe as you mentioned, does it run, or not?