# Adding custom DLL to PyQGIS script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, dll

I am trying to implement a VLC player control into a PyQGIS script.

There is [`python-vlc`](https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/) package that should be run with VLC Player installed. I have installed this package through OSGeo4W.bat but when I try `import vlc` Python says that:

> specific DLL cannot be found

It's a `libvlc.dll` lib which is mandatory for making the VLC run in Python.

Full error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 798, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 220, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 176, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL('.\\' + libname)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I looked through GIS SE, there were also cases when custom DLLs couldn't be imported through `ctypes.CDLL(dll_path)` nor with `os.add_dll_directory(path)`.

Here is a similar case: [Using ctypes for QGIS Python plugin to bind DLL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/395568/77806). Unfortunately, there wasn't a solution.

Moreover, `add_dll_directory()` method is missing in the `os` module in QGIS. Has anyone also tried to add custom DLLs to PyQGIS script/plugin? What workaround can be found here?

Comment: In my QGIS 3.28 I can see the `add_dll_directory` method from the `os` library

Comment: @Taras hmm, looks like I have to update my QGIS

Comment: The same with QGIS 3.24. Which version is yours? Python 3.7: I don't remember which QGIS version has it for the last time.

Comment: @Taras I had 3.16 on home PC. Tested on 3.22.9, everything is working now. Seems like side DLL support was added with newer versions of QGIS and Python

Comment: `add_dll_directory()` was firstly represented in Python 3.8, see this: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory

Comment: Also check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214852/python-module-dlls